# Como formato esse número em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um pequeno sistema que trabalha com bitcoins, pra quem não sabe, a moeda bitcoin tem o seguinte formato (0.00000000), este é meu mini-sistema:

```
//neste caso, o bet = 0.00000001 e o inc 150

var bet    = $('#btc').val();

// este inc é um incremento em porcentagem
var inc    = $('#inc').val();

//aqui o inc é transformado em decimal para facilitar
var vbet   = inc/100;

// aqui eu multiplico o bet por 100 milhoes para transforma-lo em numero inteiro
bet        = bet * 100000000;

vbet       = bet + (vbet * bet);

vbet       = Math.round(vbet);

// aqui o valor é novamente transformado em btc dividindo por 100 milhoes
vbet       = vbet / 100000000;

alert(vbet);
// porém o valor que aparece no alert é 3e-8
```

Preciso de ajuda para formatar este número, no php eu uso number_format(numero,casas_decimais), existe alguma função js que faça a mesma coisa?

Comment: Acredito que ja tenha algo a respeito na rede, vou procurar

Comment: Eu tentei procurar, mas não achei, talvez porque eu não saiba os termos certos a procurar, estou no aguardo!

Comment: Acho que a resposta do emanuelsn já satisfaz (?), Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/hhwwyxfq/

Comment: perfeito, muito obg!